# Interpreting sql numeric data type

Tags: sql

I have a database of an application, the price column is of type NUMERIC(4,2) , i know that 4 is the precision and 2 is the scale,,

but values are different than what i see in the application,, here are some example,

```
in db : 162.25
in app: 33.25
--
in db : 27
in app: 6
..
in db : 139.8
in app: 28.8
```

how to interpret this ?

Edit:
here's the create statment of the table

```
CREATE TABLE persons( ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,FirstName VARCHAR(86) ,LastName VARCHAR(100) ,City NUMERIC(4,2) ,OldPrice NUMERIC(4,2) ,Company VARCHAR(54) ,SRDE VARCHAR(60) ,GI VARCHAR(1000) )
```

i guess the new price is the "city" column since it's the only other numeric

here's a screenshot of "city" and "old price"

[image]

Comment: You are comparing values in the wrong columns.

Comment: Most likely you are looking at a value the application already processed in some way. The values are roughly a factor 5 apart, with 27 / 6 being exactly 4.5. The database isn't the one making that adjustment.

Comment: Some database vendors might have provided some kind of formatting function.. MySQL/SQL Server (MSSQL), PostgreSQL for example have `FORMAT()`

Comment: pretty sure that 162.25 does not fit in numeric(4,2)

Comment: All that screenshot does is prove that what you're seeing is not the actual data in the database, because that data won't *fit* in the database. A `NUMERIC(4,2)` can hold only 4 digits *in total*. `SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(4,2), 103.5)` will overflow. You're looking at different columns, or a different table, or a view, or data already processed by your application.

Comment: What database are you using? sqlite by any chance?

Comment: yes, sqlite, i'm not sure if i'm allowed to upload part of the db and share the link in the comments, am I ?